# How to select where in the image the thumbnail will show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I've done a lot of research on this subject, but could not find anything.
I want to make a thumbnail similar to the way it is done on Facebook.
You upload your picture and select the area in the photo the will show on the thumbnail version of the image.
I have looked at the documentation for the ImageMagick (RMagick) and Paperclip gems for Ruby on Rails and I do not think they have this feature.
Is there a gem for this? How should it be done?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Cupcake but actually gems are not softwares.

Comment: Gems are code libraries, which makes them software.

Comment: Yes, gems are code libraries, and code libraries are not softwares.